# Why does my query to Purchases.products in Google Player Developer Api take more than 40s to respond?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

We use Purchases.products in Google Play Developer Api from our backend to validate purchases made by our client Android app.
This use to work fine, but now the processing of a valid purchase takes 20-40 seconds to complete. It still works though.

My question is: What has changed to cause such behaviour, and is there a different approach to validate purchases that should be used now?
It is a very popular app that generates an average of 16k requests per day, so I've been thinking that maybe we are being throttled? If so, how do I find out?

I already updated to the latest version of the Google API library for .NET, and nothing changed.
The response is ~1 second if I pass an invalid receipt in the request.

The code is something similar to this:

```cs
public void ValidatePurchase(string productId, string receipt, string bundleId, string clientEmail, string privateKey)
{
    var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(clientEmail)
    {
        Scopes = new[] { AndroidPublisherService.Scope.Androidpublisher }
    }.FromPrivateKey(privateKey));

    // Create the service.
    var service = new AndroidPublisherService(initializer: new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential
    });

    service.Purchases.Products.Get(bundleId, productId, receipt).Execute();
}
```

It works, but takes 20-40 seconds to complete, which is unacceptable.

Edit: I changed my actual code to re-use the AndroidPublisherService instance like suggested in Chris' comment. As I kind of expected, it made no difference.

Also worth noting: when validating purchases from other apps, using the same service, even ones using the same account, the responses are as fast as they should be.

Comment: Are you creating a new `AndroidPublisherService` for each request? If so, this could cause problems due to too many http clients; it may be worth trying sharing a service instance.

Comment: I changed my code to do that, but it made no difference.

Comment: I guess we'll never know what the problem is...